# Using a textfile with mailadresses to sent emails to

Tags: c#, smtp

I now use

`Message.to.add(xxxx@gmail.com);`

`Message.to.add(xxxx2@gmail.com);`

Which works fine but these mail adresses need to be able to be changed By the user.

Can I take these mail adresses from a simple textfile with on each line a mail adres?

```
const string file = "Emailontvangersconfig.txt";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
{
    string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
    foreach (string Line in Lines)

    //how do i add these to the message.to.add() and do i add all of them to one message.to.add?

}
else
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, "");
}
```

Comment: `Message.To.Add(Line);` ?

Comment: Of course you can. a `String` is a `String`, regardless of where it comes from. You already know how to add a `String` containing an address because you're already doing it. `Line` is a `String` containing a address. Do what you did before.

Comment: @DiplomancyNotWar Can i place this line anywhere or only on the foreach block?

Comment: @Duivelbryan If you want it to be part of the foreach then it needs to be immediately after it (either next to it or on the line below it, etc.) otherwise it won't be part of the `foreach`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar guess my code formatting is screwed up. I didn't place it inside the foreach. And now i am getting the name Line does not exist in the current context.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywSbb.png)

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar. So i put all my email code inside the foreach. Which now it can find the Line string. But now it sents 3 mails to the first mail adress 2 mails to the second and 1 mail to the last and 3th email. Because of the foreach. Can i somehow take my email code out of it while taking the string Line 'with me'

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say what you've done wrong. I'm not sure why you put everything in the `foreach` when you only want the e-mail adding part in the `foreach`. Only the first statement (to the first `;`) attached to the `foreach` is part of it unless you use `{` and `}` to allow multiple statements per iteration of the loop.

Comment: Well you just made my light go on. It works now. Thanks for the great help. It was a code formatting issue. Where i placed the stuff. Still got a lot to learn.

Comment: Well, don't be discouraged. This place sometimes isn't the most forgiving towards beginner questions (myself included), but all of us were beginners at one point and I certainly made a lot of stupid mistakes, had trouble understanding "simple" things, etc. early on. Just keep at it and you'll get better :)

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging words. Ill try my best. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the comments from @DiplomacyNotWar and @John i basically had the correct code but my other code formatting was wrong.

````
const string file = "Emailontvangersconfig.txt";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
{
    string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
    foreach (string Line in Lines)
      message.to.add(Line)

}
else
{
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, "");
}      

     


//Rest of the email sending code


     ```
````